# What is a good word to describe someone who genuinely tries to do good but is often perceived wrongly, or doing bad?

Tags: word-choice

What is a good word to describe someone who genuinely tries to do good but is often perceived wrongly, or who is doing bad?  I know of a person who genuinely tries to do the right thing but ends up being attacked by others.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What words have you researched, and why didn't they work? Could you provide an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost answered your own question. There is an expression "do-gooder". A do-gooder is someone who is trying to help, but other people disapprove of their actions or method.

See the Cambridge dictionary [definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-gooder).

Comment: Thank you very much!